# Centering all added images in a createdElement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, alignment

I'd like to know how it would be possible to center all dinamically added images to a created element in JavaScript.

```
var imagePlaceholder = document.createElement('image-placeholder')

for (i = 0; i < imgstoload.length; i++) {

  imgstoload[i].onload = function() {

    […]

    imagePlaceholder.appendChild(imgstoload[t]);
    […]
  }

}
```

So, if 1 image is loaded, it should show at the center of image-placeholder. If 2 were the ones to be loaded (considering that the image fills a 20% of the image-placeholder) from 0 to 20%, it would show blank space, from 20% to 40% the first image, from 40% to 60% blank space, from 60% to 80% the other image and from 80% to 100% blank space again.

The point is that all images get centered.
Which would be a possible way to do this?

So far, I've tried the following to no avail:

```
imagePlaceholder.display="block"
imagePlaceholder.style.margin="auto"
```

and

```
imagePlaceholder.style.align="center"
```

Followin Wezelkrozum suggestion I've tried the following in the style tag of my HTML web page:

```
<style>
  […]
  #image-placeholder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  }
 </style>
```

But not only it does not work, it makes other components that were properly displaying to display in a wrong way.

Am I doing anyhing wrong?

Comment: I think you are looking for the space-evenly feature in flexbox:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/#article-header-id-1

Comment: @Wezelkrozum, space-around would fit me best, anyway I'm not able to make it work, I'm editing question to post what I'm trying.

Answer (score 1):

Use display flex with space-around is easier option here.

```css
.image-placeholder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-placeholder">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
```